# Не могу создать шаблона для кастомной таксономии

Tags: php, wordpress, php7

я создал катомную таксономию, но не могу создать шаблон для её термов. Таксономия называется forum.
Пробовал: category-forum.php; taxonomy-forum.php; taxonomy.php;
Выдаёт ошибку 404.

```html
add_action( 'init', 'create_snews', 0 );
function create_snews () {
 $args = array(
  'label' => _x( 'Темы форума', 'taxonomy general name' ),
  'labels' => array(
  'name' => _x( 'Темы форума', 'taxonomy general name' ),
  'singular_name' => _x( 'R', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
  'menu_name' => __( 'Темы форума' ),
  'all_items' => __( 'Все темы' ),
  'edit_item' => __( 'Изменить тему' ),
  'view_item' => __( 'Просмотреть тему' ),
  'update_item' => __( 'Обновить тему' ),
  'add_new_item' => __( 'Добавить тему' ),
  'new_item_name' => __( 'Название' ),
  'parent_item' => __( 'Родительская' ),
  'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Родительская:' ),
  'search_items' => __( 'Поиск темы' ),
  'popular_items' => null,
  'separate_items_with_commas' => null,
  'add_or_remove_items' => null,
  'choose_from_most_used' => null,
     'not_found' => __( 'Тема не найдена.' ),
    ),
    'public' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_in_menu' => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
    'show_tagcloud' => true,
    'show_in_quick_edit' => true,
    'meta_box_cb' => null,
    'show_admin_column' => false,
    'description' => '',
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'update_count_callback' => '',
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => array(
  'slug' => 'forum',
  'with_front' => false,
  'hierarchical' => true,
  'ep_mask' => EP_NONE,
 ),
    'sort' => null,
    '_builtin' => false,
);
    register_taxonomy( 'forum', array('forum'), $args );
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Настройки - Постоянные ссылки - Сохранить.

Comment: Я уже это сделал.